# Android: Drag and Drop doesn't work if view is moving (TranslateAnimation)

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-animation

If the drop is on the starting position of view that is translating then it accepts drop but view itself is in motion with TranslateAnimation, does Android make a shadow of view while animating?

Comment: Please rewrite your question. To me it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I figured it out that's how Android works. let me answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android framework won't actually move the original view from it's position when we move with translate animation, so anything we try to drop on view in motion won't work as view is still in original position.